# Searchkick Aggregations behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am working with the Searchkick Gem and Elastic search and am trying to understand the aggregations behavior.

I have three facets (Aggregations): City, State and Company.

If I filter by any one of them, the counts of other two are reduced to reflect the total in the result set.  But the selected facet comes back with all values.  So say I had 100 items in the index, and I filtered by a Company that had 2 total items in the index, the City and State counts are updated to reflect no more than 2.  But the Company count remains at 100.

Example (filtered to City=Atlanta)

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "filter": {
                  "and": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "featured": true
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "boost_factor": 1000
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   },
   "size": 20,
   "from": 0,
   "post_filter": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "expiration_date": {
                     "from": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                     "include_lower": true
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range": {
                  "created_at": {
                     "to": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                     "include_upper": true
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "published": true
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "tenant_id": 4
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "city": "Atlanta"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "company": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "expiration_date": {
                           "from": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_lower": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                           "to": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_upper": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "published": true
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "tenant_id": 4
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "city": "Atlanta"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "company": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "company",
                  "size": 10
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "city": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "expiration_date": {
                           "from": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_lower": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                           "to": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_upper": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "published": true
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "tenant_id": 4
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "city": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "city",
                  "size": 10
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "state": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "expiration_date": {
                           "from": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_lower": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                           "to": "2016-08-18T23:07:15.670-04:00",
                           "include_upper": true
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "published": true
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "tenant_id": 4
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "city": "Atlanta"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "state": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "state",
                  "size": 10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "fields": []
}
```

Result (2 result returned, but 58 City Aggregations come back).  Note Company and City return correct # of Aggregations:

```
{
   "took": 114,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "jobs_development_20160818140128648",
            "_type": "job",
            "_id": "457134",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "jobs_development_20160818140128648",
            "_type": "job",
            "_id": "457137",
            "_score": 1
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "city": {
         "doc_count": 58,
         "city": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 19,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Los Angeles",
                  "doc_count": 8
               },
               {
                  "key": "London",
                  "doc_count": 7
               },
               {
                  "key": "New York",
                  "doc_count": 7
               },
               {
                  "key": "Burbank",
                  "doc_count": 5
               },
               {
                  "key": "Pasig",
                  "doc_count": 3
               },
               {
                  "key": "Atlanta",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "Chicago",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "Culver City",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "London Borough of Hackney",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "Birmingham",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "company": {
         "doc_count": 2,
         "company": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Second Story",
                  "doc_count": 2
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "state": {
         "doc_count": 2,
         "state": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Georgia",
                  "doc_count": 2
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What am I missing? Is this correct behavior?

Comment: Although your query can be further optimized, the query and the response  look correct to me. This is generally how multi-category facets behave. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: thanks @bittusarkar I would expect the results to only come back with at most 2 cities, since there are only 2 results.  Instead it comes back with 58?

Comment: And that should be correct. Just think about it a little. You have already filtered on `"Atlanta"` city so in the result you are expecting, you'll simply get `"Atlanta" -> 2`. I don't think that is much useful. But if you want it anyways, just add the `city` filter in `city` aggregations just like you added that filter in the other two aggregations.